# How can I surpass or skip a method using JUNIT?

Tags: java, junit, powermock, easymock, powermockito

I have a block of code for which I need to test .Lets say

```
Class MainClass{    
   public void startProcess() {     
      ----Some Logic to generate fileName; 
          uploadFile(fileName);     
       }

  private static void uploadFile(String key) {    
      fileUpload();    
      deleteFile();    
  }    
}
```

I want to write a JUNIT test which will call startProcess but either skip the uploadFile line or just ignore any lines present in uploadFile method .

I tried to use powerMock but it doesnt work . Below is my code

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MainClass.class)
public class MainClassTest {         
   @Test
   public void teststartProcess() throws Exception {
     processor=PowerMock.createPartialMock(MainClass.class,"uploadFile");
     PowerMock.expectPrivate(processor , "uploadFile", "xyz").andAnswer(
       new IAnswer<Void>() {
       @Override
       public Void answer() throws Throwable {
         System.out.println("Invoked!");
         return null;
       }
    }).atLeastOnce();
  }
}
```

But it does't override the method uploadFile to just print invoked . It calls fileUpload and deleteFile instead of just skipping the lines and print invoke .

My basic goal is to mock the method uploadFile to just print

```
private void uploadFile(String key) {
  System.out.println("Invoked");
}
```

I know it's possible using Mockito but we can use either PowerMock or EasyMock .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to go the way with over complicated tests you should consider to refactor your code so that it is testable. From what you provided I would move the file functionality to another class.
something like this:

```
public class MainClass {
    private final FileUploader fileUploader;

    public MainClass(FileUploader fileUploader) {
        this.fileUploader= fileUploader;
    }

    public void startProcess() {
        fileUploader.uploadFile(fileName);
    }
}
```

With this refactoring you gain the possibility to use plain mocking for the test:

```
String fileName = "foo";
FileUploader fileUploader = mock(FileUploader.class);

MainClass classUnderTest = new MainClass(fileUploader);
classUnderTest.startProcess();

verify(fileUploader, times(1)).uploadFile(fileName);
```

An additional benefit is that testing the fileUploader becomes also easy. As you can see I also got rid of all the complicated Partial mocking and private testing.

Comment: Exactly ,but issue is that we can't change the main code .

Comment: @arpitjoshi asking provokingly: What is the point in testing code which you can't/won't change?

Comment: Well I agree that there is no point in testing code which we can't change ,but we want to test for the logic present in startProcess method ,because once upload is called it deletes the file from local system . And the logic create some keys which we need to check .

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the mock object to replay mode before calling the method under test and you have to tell Powermock to work on a static method:

```
mockStaticStrict(MainClass.class,method(MainClass.class, "uploadFile"));

PowerMock.replay(processor);
processor.startProcess();
```

See [Mocking private methods](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockPrivate) for further information on this.

I *highly suggest* to refactor this code and make it testable.

Comment: Well I tried this one but doesnt seem to make any change because it goes into the upload file call and performs the functions present in upload file method.

Comment: @arpitjoshi For me it worked, but only if I had the replay call.

Comment: Adding the below in addition to what you mentioned worked for me 
mockStaticStrict(MainClass.class,method(MainClass.class, "uploadFile"));
Basically it's my bad ,I forgot to mentioned static in uploadFile method .But very much thanks .Can you add mockStaticStrict in your answer ,so it may be helpful for other people

Comment: @arpitjoshi That is another red flag which tells you that you should refactor your code. I understand that this answer solved your current problem, but please consider marking the other answer as accepted as this is (in my opinion) the far better solution.

Comment: have Marked the answer as accepted ,thanks for your solution.